# Which store should I use: Document storage or SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, data-storage

I'm pulling a list of text posts from an API. Each post has a title and description. I need to persist all of them in my iPhone app.

Which storage should I use ? Should I use Document storage or should I use CoreData SQLite store?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform query on them, it is better to use core data or sqlite. Otherwise, I think document file is ok.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is a good and efficient way to persist data in your app. But consider that in such case is up to you to clean up too old data to avoid using too much storage space in your device. Besides consider that CoreData is very good to persist object relationships, while in your case probably you don't need to persist an object graph but just a list of post data and so you will not take benefit of the querying feature of CoreData.

But if you're using a network based API you may also take benefit of the data caching provide by the API and use the iOS network caching mechanism. To simplify things, you can take advantage of opensourced network frameworks such as [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) which will persist the cached data in the file system and will get rid of them as soon as they expire or after a customizable time (days, weeks, months). Or if you don't want to use a 3rd party tool, you can still use the NSURLCache object provided by Apple with iOS. This approach is much more simpler than core data one: in such case you will still fetch data from the network and if it has been cached yet no network path will be followed and data will be directly taken from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

With iCloud, documents make more sense but @yibuyiqu is right that if you want to query against your data a DB is best.

You can put your searchable and initially displayable data in the DB and have it point to the file that holds the full data (use a GUID for the filename).  This way if you use iCloud your data is ready to export because it's already in a document, which it expects.

Another benefit is search performance goes up the less data there is in the DB.  So if you're storing images or other heavy data, having that external to the DB is best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIManagedDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the benefits of both.  You'll also be in a position to add iCloud syncing later.